# Як буде українською Full-Stack Developer?

Tags: переклад

Варіанти мінімального засвоєння назви спеціальності такі:

**Full stack developer** - навіть не перекладено

**Full stack розробник** - частковий, бо коли developer ще можна впевнено перекласти як розробник, то з першою частиною проблема

**фул стек розробник** - транслітерація + переклад

Ну й інші гібриди:

> Оскільки ви не можете передбачити зміни на ринку вам потрібно зробити
>   перевірку без небажаних затрат. I в цій ситуації робота з **фулстек
>   розробником** являється виграшною.

[medium.com](https://medium.com/@IvanZmerzlyi/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%96%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F-full-stack-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-dd81905af823)

> **Fullstack-розробник** – це фахівець, здатний створити з нуля веб-застосування

[echo.lviv.ua](http://echo.lviv.ua/dev/6264)

Тиражоване пояснення спеціальності в інеті:

> Being a Full-Stack Developer doesn’t mean that you have necessarily
>   mastered everything required to work with the front-end or back-end,
>   but it means that you are able to work on both sides and understand
>   what is going on when building an application.

[quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-full-stack-developer)

Отож, чи є українські слова, якими можна вдало перекласти Full-Stack Developer?

Comment: Як програміст (хоч і не веб) скажу, що краще не треба. Це як раз той випадок коли краще запозичувати слово, а не вигадувати щось своє.

Comment: [What does full-stack developer mean?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-full-stack-developer-mean). *Універсальний розробник* може працювати з будь-яким шаром програмного забезпечення. Зазвичай додають ще той самий стек технологій. Наприклад, *Універсальний розробник (на) C#*, *Універсальний розробник (на) Java* та т.і.

Answer (score 7):

Очевидно, в українських словниках цього терміну не існує, так само як і необхідних складових цієї спеціалізації — фронтенд та бекенд розробник.
Коректним є використання трьох варіантів, адже в українській мові аналогів цієї спеціалізації поки що немає:

**1. Фулстек-розробник**

Приклади вживання схожого терміну "Фронтенд-розробник":

> - Що вивчати ***фронтенд-розробнику*** в 2018 році?
>     Програмування # розвиток 
>      У цій статті докладно розглянемо, що слід вивчати ***фронтенд-розробнику***, щоб стати затребуваним фронтендером в 2018 році.
>     Чим займається ***фронтенд-розробник***?
>     Кожне веб-додаток складається з двох частин: фронтенда - клієнтської частини веб-додатки, яка містить все, що ви бачите і з чим взаємодієте в браузері як користувач додатка, і бекенд, або серверної частини, в якій зберігаються дані веб-додатки, оновлюються і обробляються, а потім передаються клієнтської частини. — [Джерело](https://www.facebook.com/iabs.uz/posts/%D1%89%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-2018-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-______________/1877914948937343/)
> - Наталія Теплухіна (GitLab) — ***фронтенд-розробник***, великий поціновувач фреймворку Vue.js та один з контриб’юторів до Vue-екосистеми. Працює Senior Frontend Engineer в компанії GitLab. — [Джерело](https://dou.ua/calendar/24106/)

**2. Фулстек розробник**

Приклади вживання схожого терміну "Фронтенд розробник":

> - Чому варто оволодіти професією ***Фронтенд розробника***? Бажаєш Творити? Саме ***фронтенд розробник*** робить видиму для клієнта красу. Будь-яка мінімальна робота вже помітна оку, на противагу розробці бекенду, де все «під капотом». Візуально помітний розвиток проекту надихає на роботу, адже одразу результат можна побачити. — [Джерело](http://academy.softgroup.ua/uk/angularjs)
> - Професії: Front-End Developer (Фронтенд Розробник), C#/.Net Back-End Developer (C#/.Net Бекенд Розробник). — [Джерело](http://www.fullstack.com.ua/home/developer-way)

**3. Фул-стек розробник**

Приклади вживання схожого терміну "Фронт-енд розробник":

> - ***Фронт-енд розробник*** (з англ. «Front-end developer») —  це програміст, що займається розробкою користувацького інтерфейсу, тобто зовнішньої публічної частини сайту в браузері. Головне завдання ***фронт-енд розробника*** — зробити максимально зручним взаємодію користувачів з сайтом або веб-додатком. — [Джерело](https://talent.ua/uk/resume-shablon/frontend_developer)

Зазначу, що "Універсальний розробник" не підходить, адже цей термін досить розмитий й може означати будь-що. Наприклад, так можна сказати про розробника, який знає декілька мов програмування, але це не означає, що він знає мови програмування, необхідні як для створення бекенду, так і для створення фронтенду. В той же час, "Фулстек розробник" є досить конкретним поняттям й означає, що людина вправно володіє як навичками фронтенд розробника, так і бекенд розробника. Цього достатньо, щоб самому з нуля створити будь-яку програму (веб, десктопну, тощо).

Comment: *Front-end* і *back-end* можна перекласти як *передок* і *задок*.

Comment: @Yola, якось занадто непристойно виходитиме, по-моєму.

Comment: @moonrider_unchained, я можу погодитися з аргументацією, але по-моєму, «фул стек розробник» не може писатися трьома окремими словами. Це або «фулстек-розробник», або в крайньому разі «фул-стек-розробник» — аналогічно до «інтернет-провайдер», «онлайн-словник» тощо. Окремо перед іменником може писатися лише повноцінно відмінюваний прикметник (типу «інтернетний провайдер», «онлайновий словник», «фулстековий розробник»), але не невідмінювані фрагменти (типу «інтернет-[щось]», «онлайн-[щось]», «фул(-)стек-[щось]»).

Comment: @Sasha Погоджуюсь з отриманими зауваженнями. Провів більш глибоке дослідження питання на базі того, як вживаються схожі терміни "фронтенд розробник" або "бекенд розробник". Виправив відповідь, додав приклади вживання та посилання на джерела.

Comment: Мені, якщо чесно, все ще здається, що правильний лише перший варіант. Адже ми можемо дивитися, як люди пишуть, щоб прогнозувати, яке слово ймовірніше ввійде в загальний обіг — але при цьому ми маємо враховувати, що люди не завжди пишуть правильно (вони пишуть і «по моєму, по твоєму», і «не зрозуміло, не гарна», і інше — що вже казати про запозичені слова/конструкції, на які сильно впливає граматика мови-джерела). У виборі разом/дефісно/окремо я би радше надавав перевагу традиції, а не сучасній статистиці. Однак — **не можу не поставити плюса**.

Answer (score 1):

Мабуть, це не найбільш точний відповідник, але я переклав би як «**розробник повного циклу**».

<sub>Приклади вживання:</sub>

- > <sub>Пропозицій роботи є багато</sub>
  >   <sub>Кожен перший проект потребує фронтендера. Навіть «суто бекендному» проекту необхідне візуальне відображення, тому фронтенд розробник завжди користується попитом. При цьому, «суто фронтендна» мова JavaScript наразі використовується і на бекенді, наприклад у NodeJS. А тому фронтендер зможе допомогти бекендеру, чи перекваліфікуватись на **розробника повного циклу**, тоді як бекендеру це буде зробити важче без додаткового навчання. Незважаючи на велику конкуренцію, робота є та буде завжди.</sub>
  >   <sub>// [Angular / JavaScript | SoftGroup Academy](http://academy.softgroup.ua/uk/angularjs)</sub>
- > <sub>Також будуть задіяні наступні співробітники ГО «Укрмедіа»:</sub>
  >   <sub>• Шепетко Олександр, **веб-розробник повного циклу**.</sub>
  >   <sub>// [Заява на участь у міському конкурсі проектів «Громадська перспектива: прозора влада та активна громада»](https://dsk.kyivcity.gov.ua/files/2018/2/14/9.pdf)</sub>
- > <sub>Новостворювана спеціалізація передбачає підготовку ІТ спеціалістів новітніх профілів, з професійними навичками які є дуже затребувані вже сьогодні:</sub>
  >   <sub>JAVA розробник різних рівнів - від мобільних паристроїв до веб базованих корпоративних інфраструктурних систем,</sub>
  >   <sub>**WEB розробник повного циклу** - зі знаннями різних платформ та суміжними професіями в широкому асортименті, наприклад: дизайнер баз даних, мережевий адміністратор менеджер ІТ проектів, веб дизайнер</sub>
  >   <sub>// [Презентація «Інтернет технології, мобільний комп’ютинг та веб розробка. Програма підготовки рівнів бакалавр-магістр» від кафедри інформаційних систем і технологій Інституту підприємництва та перспективних технологій Національного університету «Львівська політехніка»](https://www.slideshare.net/rthasko/future4kist-14-1-54723424)</sub>
- > <sub>Мені потрібно вибрати між «фронтенд», «бекенд» і розробкою повного циклу</sub>
  >   <sub>Після того, як ви спробували обидва варіанти розробки, настав час робити вибір. Якщо ви не встигли спробувати – зверніться до попереднього розділу статті, щоб заповнити прогалини у ваших знаннях.</sub>
  >   <sub>До цього моменту ви писали два типу коду. Один призначений для взаємодії з користувачем, інший – з даними. Що ви віддаєте перевагу?</sub>
  >   <sub>Взаємодія з користувачем? Вітаю, ви фронтенд-розробник!</sub>
  >   <sub>Взаємодія з даними? Вітаю, ви бекенд-розробник!</sub>
  >   <sub>Обидва? Вітаю, ви **розробник повного циклу**!</sub>
  >   <sub>Нічого не сподобалося? Вітаю, веб-розробка – це не для вас. Радійте, що ви зрозуміли це зараз, і не втратили купу часу і грошей. Не готові здаватися? Може, вам не попався мову, який припав би вам по душі? Спробуйте вивчити інші мови в розділі «Я хочу бути бекенд-розробником».</sub>
  >   <sub>// [Судячи з усього, машинний переклад російської статті «Как стать профессиональным веб-разработчиком: практическое руководство», який, однак, уже встигли перепублікувати в декількох місцях](https://habr.com/en/post/303896/)</sub>
- > <sub>Доброго часу доби.</sub>
  >   <sub>Я **веб-розробник (повного циклу)**. Маю досвід у проектуванні та реалізації баз даних.</sub>
  >   <sub>Чи не могли б Ви надати більш детальну інформацію щодо роботи?</sub>
  >   <sub>Дякую!</sub>
  >   <sub>// [Заявка фрилансера на сайті freelancer.com.au](//www.freelancer.com.au/projects/database-development/project-14871660/)</sub>

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Можна піти трохи далі ніж *фулстек-розробник* і перекласти як **розробник повного стека** або **веб-розробник повного стека**.

Слово *стек* тут варто залишити, бо йдеться про стек технологій.

Приклад:

> <sub>Примітно, що JavaScript очолив відразу три рейтинги: за версією **девелоперів повного стека**, фронт-енд і бек-енд розробників.</sub>   
>   <sub>// [Опубліковано рейтинг мов програмування на Stackoverflow: лідирує JavaScript](http://www.itcluster.ck.ua/all-events/item/435-opublikovano-rejting-mov-programuvannya-na-stackoverflow-lidirue-javascript)</sub>

Comment: а мені так сподобався жарт про передок і задок...